# Check if User Data is Already in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to include functionality within the current code to prevent duplicate additions to be added to the database. This way if someone already registers their name and e-mail, a message instead will pop up to say that they have already added their information to the database. My form is using asp.net the data is populated using c#. Am I able to include something like this: `cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where pName='"+t1.Text+"' and pEmail='"+t2.Text+"'";` to achieve that?

c# Code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString2"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into[Table1](pName)values(@nm)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into[Table1](pEmail)values(@nm)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (a>0)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Inserted Sucessfully!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in short, yes, you can, and use `count(*)` to return number of records.  But better to with `Parameters` instead of string concat

Comment: Make the column Unique and after surround  your code by try-catch. If duplicate data is inserted it will through the sql exception catch the exception and display the message

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try!

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple SQL statements need to be wrapped in a suitable transaction if you want to make a larger atomic operation. Between the time you check for a row and then try to add it another process could do the same thing. Adam Smith's comment handles the issue by making the test part of the `INSERT`, hence ensuring that you won't get bitten by a _race condition_.

Comment: What is your database ?

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash My database is a .mdb file I created

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have a SELECT query first before INSERT statement. Also you can only use email as parameter on your SELECT statement and not include name since there are chance that persons have the same name.

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM tblUsers WHERE email = @email
int count = db.ExecuteReader(query);    


if (count > 0){
   return "email is already in use";
} else {
   //Call the insert statement here with try catch inside. In this way you can handle if error occur on the execution itself.
}
```

Comment: How do I get around query not being an int in this case?

Comment: my mistake if i used var instead of int to declare query. select  count should return int (numbers of record).

Comment: updated the code above. the idea is there you might need to add some modification tough.

Comment: Thanks tons! I'll do some re-working! Wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this but I am using SQL server 2014 ..Try this ..
Schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dummy](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
)
```

and query

```
  if not exists(select 1 from Dummy where Name='akash')
  insert into Dummy(Name) values('aka')
```

This is single query with returns no of row in `int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Method 2:
Create a unique CONSTRAINT and use try catch to found that no duplicate row is inserted..

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dummy] ADD  CONSTRAINT [uc_Name] UNIQUE 
NONCLUSTERED 
(
    Name ASC
)
```