# Code Not Preventing Duplicate E-mail Addresses in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code I have is allowing duplicate e-mails to be added to the database. I added a line of code before allowing entry into the database to prevent duplicate e-mail addresses to be added, however with this code I am still getting duplicate e-mails. I have provided both the form code in asp.net & the c# code. Please help.

Originally I was getting an error & I debugged the code in VS & realized that I actually had the wrong specification for the email entry, that has been corrected. In the VS debugger I see values for TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text, i also see the e-mail address passing through the string query = the issue however is that even if the e-mail is already in the database, it still gets added again. Any improvements to fix this issue with my code? Is my logic wrong perhaps?

c# code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["northwind"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail= '" + TextBox2.Text +"'";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

        var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = "email is already in use";
        }
        else {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into[Table1](pName, pEmail)values(@nm,@em)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (a>0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Inserted Sucessfully!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="height: 138px">

    Enter Name:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 12px"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    id="reqName" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    Style="color:Red"   
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!"
    runat="server"  />

    <br />
    Enter Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    id="ValidEmail" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" 
    Style="color:Red"
    ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Entry" 
    runat="server" />

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I suggest adding a unique constraint to the database and capturing it in your code. But you may prefer a C# option.

Comment: @penmas , firstly the query is prone to sql injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Duplicate E-mail Address Submissions c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273881/prevent-duplicate-e-mail-address-submissions-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if User Data is Already in Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252638/check-if-user-data-is-already-in-database)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` to get the row count

Original:

```
var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Suggest to change:

```
var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269651/1050927

The [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery.aspx) Method returns the number of row(s) affected by either an INSERT, an UPDATE or a DELETE. This method is to be used to perform DML (data manipulation language) statements as stated previously.

The [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) Method will return a single value in the first row, first column from a SELECT statement. This method is to be used when you expect only one value from the query to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExecuteScalar` and Convert the result to int. I also recommend you to change the sql query concatenation to parameters, and if you are using ASP.NET Validators, you must check the property `IsValid` of the page as it will tell you if the controls has passed validation (remember that users can disable javascript and post the form).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["northwind"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE pEmail= @em";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", TextBox2.Text);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecutScalar());
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "email is already in use";
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into[Table1](pName, pEmail)values(@nm, @em)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox1.Text);
                    // not need to add @em parameter, it was added previously
                    int insertedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (insertedRows > 0)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "Inserted Sucessfully!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```